# Are there any more SE1.0 sites around?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history

I know there used to be a few SE1.0 sites still around, and many got migrated to 2.0

1. Mi.Yodeya
2. MathOverflow

Some moved out of SE altogether (such as parenting).

Are any still in 1.0 mode?

Comment: Area51 is a 1.0 fork, I think.

Comment: There is a [deleted question linking some sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website). But many of them no longer exist or are no longer a 1.0 site.

Comment: [parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) is very much part of Stack Exchange and still in beta, why you think it's "moved out of SE"?

Comment: @MartijnPieters what did it do in 1.0?

Comment: Whatever it did, it is still doing it. Area51 is still active.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It just had a credit-card field in the end?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wasn't SE1.0 just selling and hosting private QA sites? For what do you need an area51?

Comment: [Why don't you take a look at it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's how it works now. Did it do this in SE1.0?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: That is what I am saying; the software used to run that site is a fork of the 1.0 codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question in a comment a while back, but I forget exactly where.

As far as I know, [PaleoHacks](http://paleohacks.com/) is the only existing SE 1.0 site. MathOverflow was recently migrated to SE 2.0, though:

[image]